# .NET Console Application Connection String Transform Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm uploading a console app as a webjob to my app service on azure. I have unloaded the application and told it to include a release config In the csproj:

```
<Content Include="App.config" />
<Content Include="App.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="App.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
</Content
```

along with this at the end:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="exists('app.$(Configuration).config')">
<!-- Generate transformed app config in the intermediate directory -->
<TransformXml Source="app.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)  $(TargetFileName).config" Transform="app.$(Configuration).config" />
<!-- Force build process to use the transformed configuration file from now on. -->
<ItemGroup>
  <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="app.config" />
  <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
    <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
  </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

On my local machine the connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Default1" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Default1;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In the App.Release.Config I have this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Default1"  connectionString="Server=tcp::NewApplication.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=NewApplication;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=NewApplicationadmin;Password=testing;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The console application works fine on my local machine, and the way in which I did my transformations on my web app is exactly the same.

However when I upload it and run it as a webjob it fails giving this error in the log:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

What would cause this in this instance?

Comment: *"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."* Seems to be pretty telling. It may be that the server is configured to only allow a single connection (or single per-app). Looks like you have a data reader that you either didn't close or forgot to close.

Comment: @RonBeyer i understand what the error is saying but it just doesn't make sense to me, wouldn't my web application repeat the same error? Sorry if i sound like an idiot I'm no expert on azure

Comment: Your local application may have a different server configuration. So no, it wouldn't necessarily show up locally.